# Trying to install discord.py but end up with permission errors

Tags: permissions, python

I just switched my  OS to Ubuntu 16.04 (first time ever using linux).

I managed to install Python 3.6 following this guide:
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install3/linux/

And I installed pip following the answer that was found on this stack overflow thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662104/how-to-install-pip-for-python-3-6-on-ubuntu-16-10

Everything worked like a charm, however, when I try to install the discord.py module using `python3.6 -m pip install -U discord.py`, I am thrown a permission error on everything it tries to install.

```
Collecting discord.py
Collecting aiohttp<1.1.0,>=1.0.0 (from discord.py)
Collecting websockets<4.0,>=3.1 (from discord.py)
  Using cached websockets-3.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting chardet (from aiohttp<1.1.0,>=1.0.0->discord.py)
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting multidict>=2.0 (from aiohttp<1.1.0,>=1.0.0->discord.py)
  Using cached multidict-3.1.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting async-timeout (from aiohttp<1.1.0,>=1.0.0->discord.py)
  Using cached async_timeout-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: chardet, multidict, async-timeout, aiohttp,    websockets, discord.py
  Found existing installation: chardet 2.3.0
    Uninstalling chardet-2.3.0:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 544, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3/dist- packages/chardet' -> '/tmp/pip-kssx4kah-uninstall/usr/lib/python3/dist- packages/chardet'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line    215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py",  line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line  778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
   renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py",    line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 556, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 480, in rmtree
_    rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 438, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 436, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(name, dir_fd=topfd)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'jpcntx.py'
```

This is just one of the error messages I get, I also get other ones such as

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/websockets'
```

and

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/async_timeout
```

as well as

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/multidict-3.1.3.dist-info'
```

Comment: My friend please read up a bit on Ubuntu, python comes pre-installed that being said use `sudo` before that command

Comment: Wow, I completely forgot about adding  sudo. Thanks for pointing out that stupid mistake.

Comment: Please don't forget the `-H` flag with `sudo` :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take the time to read a bit about how Ubuntu and linux as a whole works, that command should have been:

```
sudo -H pip install  <package_name>
```

Please note a few things:

1. If you do `pip --version` or `pip3 --version` you will see what version of python goes with that `pip` command:

   ```
   pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
   ```
2. If you do `pip2 --version` then we see `python 2.*`:

   ```
   pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
   ```
3. Python is already there so need to re-install it.
4. In Ubuntu `pip` and `pip3` use `python 3.*`, but `pip2` uses `python 2.*`

Important:

```
-H, --set-home

             Request that the security policy set the HOME environment variable to the home directory specified by the target user's password database
             entry.  Depending on the policy, this may be the default behavior.
```